# Which system calls are not interrupted by a signal?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, kernel, signals

AFAIK, most of the system calls on linux/unix are interrupted when a signal is received. According to the blog post below, there are some system calls that are not interrupted:

> In general function that return immediately (don't wait for any I/O operation to complete or sleep) are not interruptible like socket(2) which just allocates a socket and doesn't wait for anything.

http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals?page=5

Is there a list of those kind of functions? Any links related to this topic would be helpful.

Comment: When a signal is blocked, it does not "interrupt" any system call. And there could be some boundary cases with some NFS mounted filesystems. But why do you care?

Comment: I am afraid I don't get you. What means "signal is blocked"? To clarify, I am talking about the interruption of syscalls with EINTR. 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html (Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers)
What is the mechanism that kernel uses to decide which call is interruptible and which one is not? (if the story with "socket()" is true).

Comment: The specification (the man page) of each syscall tells if it can get `EINTR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the mechanism that kernel uses to decide which call is
>   interruptible and which one is not? (if the story with "socket()" is
>   true)

The task have bitmask, which can be set with [set_task_state](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=4.4#L261) to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` and `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` ( defined [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=4.4#L209) ).

> Is there a list of those kind of functions?

I don't think, that there is list of uninterruptible functions. You can search for usages of `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` ( like [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=4.4;i=TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE) )

Edit: [example](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/locking/mutex.c?v=4.4#L560) of checking this flag with [signal_pending_state](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=4.4#L2913)